# Server recieves message after client disconnects

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask

In my project there is a server that sits for clients and serves them.

The server---- Main

```
    ss = new ServerSocket(12345);
    System.out.println("Server started..");
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Waiting For clients...");
        Socket client = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Got client...");
        Thread t = new Thread(new Handler(client));
        t.start();
        //exe.execute(new Handler(client));

    }
```

This is in the main method, the server creates an infinite loop (thread) that will accept incoming connections. Once a connection has been received the server will create a new Handler object that takes the client who has connected as an argument.

The Handler class

```
    public class Handler implements Runnable {

    Socket client;

    public Handler(Socket client) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.client = client;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //streams 
        try {
            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out);

            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String s = null;

            while((s=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {

                //will switch on string or convert to json object
                System.out.println("Recieved: " + s);
            }
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

In this class the main objective is to handle the clients request. So  the constructor initializes the socket object to it's owning instance.

in the run method the objects are instantiated, and then there is an infinite loop which is suppose to print any incoming messages from clients.

The loop will break when the client disconnects, and this is where the `close()`
method is called, to gracefully close and release resources. With this the thread ends.

The Client - (Android)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String ip = "192.168.0.18";
    final int port = 12345;
    Socket client;
    OutputStream out;
    PrintWriter writer;

    InputStream in;
    BufferedReader reader;
    final String TAG = "Debug: ";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ConnectToServer().execute();
        new SendToServer().execute();


    }

    class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try {
                client = new Socket(ip,port);
                //Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: connected to server");
                //set streams
                out = client.getOutputStream();
                writer = new PrintWriter(out);

                in = client.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Sent");



            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    class SendToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            writer.write("lol");
            writer.flush();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Last time I played with Android Studio was a year ago or so, and I am very positive that network/IO operations were possible to run on the main thread. But the golden rule implies to not block the main thread, and there are some blocking methods.

I chose to use the `AsyncTask` interface since it encapsulates the lower level `Thread` class (Easier to use/ understand the life cycle for me).

The `ConnectToServer` class successfully connects to the server, but once the `SendToServer`class is called,  the server doesn't receive the message.

Once I disconnect the client (terminate the app) the server then prints out the messages.

Why is the server receiving the messages after the client disconnects?

Comment: why do you have two async tasks?

Comment: @Pooya from my understanding, I do not close the connection. The connection is closed when the Android client terminates the application. When an application closes it will return either a 0 or -1 to the server, and the BufferedReader  object will read this and break out of the loop, and then close the streams and sockets.

Comment: @Pooya One AsyncTask is for connecting to the server, another AsynTask is to send data to the server.

Comment: just a wild guess but worth a try: change "writer" value to be: writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream())),true);

Comment: @Pooya didn't work, with this modification, the server does not receive the message whilst the client is connected. The server receives the message when the client disconnects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator to the message being sent, or use `println()` instead of `write()`.

Comment: you say I am reading lines, which is on the server. The BufferedReader object uses the readLine() method to read incoming packets I presume? 

I didn't understand what you meant by "Add a line terminator to the message being sent", however using the printLn() method did work. I don't understand why the 'write' method was implemented for. I will look to the API documentation.

Comment: I don't know what you expect a method called `readLine()` to do, but it, err, reads a line. A line terminator is`"\r\n", "\r"`, or `"\n"`, or `System.lineSeparator()`. `println((` adds a line terminator. All this is in the Javadoc.